# AspectJ Intercept call when passing parameter

Tags: java, aspectj

I am using AspectJ to log information about my business entities.

I have a class called Task, and am intercepting the getters of the task in TaskLogger aspect.

```
class Task {
    private String name;
    private Integer priority;
    ...
```

This works fine. I have now implemented an Audit class to audit and control the tasks.

I want to have a specific logging for the tasks when the Audit.audit(Object o) method is being called.

```
Task t = new Task();
...
logger.info(t.getName());   // Here my aspect is being invoked for the name getter
...
auditor.audit(t.getName()); // Here I would like to have another aspect invoked for the task nam getter
```

Example:
When logger.info() is being called, I want my LoggerAspect to print something like "Logging Task: taskName, at 15.30.32". The job is being done because my LoggerAspect intercepts the getter.

But when t.getName() is being used as a parameter of the call auditor.audit(t.getName()) I would like to be able to identify that I am calling getName() for the audit() method (or as a parameter of the audit method) and provide a different trace or a different behaviour.

I guess this can be solved by defining 2 different point cuts, but at the moment I can't find a good way to define it.

(NB: I managed to intercept audit(task). But would also be able to intercept audit(t.getName()) - Can I intercept a parameter when this parameter is the result of a call on the Task class?)

Any idea?

Thanks

Gilles